# geology problems: three-dimensional fault line - r.plane (GRASS) from polyline

Tags: grass-gis, geology

I should use the r.plane script (GRASS) but imputing a polyline (trace of my fault line) and not a point; is this possible? I could use batch process, but I should be charged a lot of points and then fonder raster.

[image]

Comment: It isn't very clear what you are asking here. Can you edit your question (just click "edit" below the question) to provide some more context (the "big picture" of what you are trying to do), what you've already tried, what the results of that were, and what you expected to happen instead. The "charged a lot of points" and "fonder raster" are particularly confusing to me.

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to use directly GRASS GIS (2D and 3D) and not GRASS from QGIS (2D)

You can use lines or points to create a fault surface

From a line with r.plane

[image]

From 3D points (contacts in the upper NW part and boreholes) with the 3D interpolation modules ([v.surf.rst](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/v.surf.rst.html) and others)

[image]

The "Geologic 3 D data visualisation" model from [GRASS GIS: Visualization and volumetric 3D examples](https://grass.osgeo.org/screenshots/3D/) (various fault surfaces) was done with 3D points

[image]